# Fixing a question for reopening

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I recently asked [How do I calculate the cost of printing a given page?](https://superuser.com/q/516695/113301) and it was closed as NARQ.

The question might have flaws, but I don't really agree it's NARQ. What had it closed is probably this part:

> I know it depends on quality of the printer itself, the type, the quality of the image being printed, the very nature of what I'm going to print, etc.

However, I thought that since the parameters to take into consideration were a reasonable little number, it wouldn't matter. And in that case, wouldn't it be *not constructive* instead?

In any case, all I'm asking, i.e. the core of my question, is:

> *What parameters should one take into account when calculating the cost?*

So I was wondering: is there a way it could be fixed to be reasonably scoped? I'd appreciate any suggestions (or also comments explaining/confirming the current closed state).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's not a lot to fix here. As far as I can see you've phrased the question correctly. You even specifically say:

> i.e. the answer should be applicable in any case; I'd like this question to provide a good reference for those who want to calculate this cost.

This is what we absolutely encourage, and the question should be as canonical as possible. You haven't focused on very specific models (which would make it too localized), and you also don't ask about personal opinion (which would have been not constructive). Given a good answer, the question would be helpful to a large number of people who are in a similar situation. I've therefore reopened it.

(And if the answer is: "It's not really possible to accurately calculate this," so be it – at least the question is well asked.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the insight. :)